# Complete trace of the function call whenever I run any contract in truffle

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

I want to see the complete trace of the function call whenever I run any contract in truffle. Can I do that. From the complete trace I mean if a function calls another function and so on, I want to see in which orders they call each other and if possible then also the values.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but Truffle has an interactive debugger built in. Have you tried it? You can read about it [here](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/debugging-a-smart-contract#debugging-the-issue).

Basically you run `truffle debug <transaction-id>` to start the debugger and see the transaction being executed step by step.

Comment: Thanks for telling about this feature of the truffle.

But my problem is that I want to generate a dynamic call graph and therefore I want to know the exact flow of the function calls. I tried to trace it through the transaction-id logged in the testrpc console but I am not getting exactly what I want. Is there any way I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like the printStackTrace() in Java? This may be helpful:

https://medium.com/tenderly/how-to-debug-solidity-smart-contracts-with-tenderly-and-truffle-da995cfe098f